# Tweets about past disasters (flood, storm, earthquake, volcanic eruption)

Tags: data-request, social-media, geohazard

Where can I download tweets about past disasters (flood, storm, earthquake, volcanic eruption) for research purposes?

Comment: See this answer from a previous question : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5580/263

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all tweets from a given Twitter #hashtag](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5570/how-to-get-all-tweets-from-a-given-twitter-hashtag)

Comment: @philshem : I'm torn on closing this as a duplicate, as they might want to search by keyword rather than solely by hashtag.

Comment: @Joe hashtags are just keywords that are clickable. With the API-search there is no difference (although hashtags come back as a structured list, in addition to being in text).

Comment: @philshem : the problem is that the other question would allow an answer to be a service that only indexed on hashtags ... whereas this question might require free-text searching for terms that haven't been indexed in advance.

Comment: With the API, searching "haiku" will return results with "#haiku". https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search